# Django getlist() bug?

Tags: python, django

I did not received any error but I know that the in the database save record is incorrect, is it a bug in getlist()? or did i miss something in code? please tell me why wrong record save in the database

```
def corevalues(request):
    coregradelevel = request.GET.get('coregradelevel')
    coreperiod = request.GET.get('coreperiod')
    marking = StudentBehaviorMarking.objects.all()
    teacher = request.GET.get('teacher')
    corevalues = CoreValues.objects.all().order_by('Display_Sequence')
    corevaluesdescription = CoreValuesDescription.objects.values('id','Description').distinct('Description').order_by('Description')
    corevaluesperiod = CoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(grading_Period=coreperiod).order_by('Display_Sequence')
    period = gradingPeriod.objects.filter(id=coreperiod).order_by('Display_Sequence')
    gradelevel = EducationLevel.objects.filter(id__in = coregradelevel).distinct().order_by('id')

    studentcorevalues = StudentsCoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(GradeLevel = gradelevel.values_list('Description'))\
        .values('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')

    student = StudentPeriodSummary.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(GradeLevel__in = gradelevel.values_list('id'))
```

this is my html code

```
<table class="tblcore">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Core Values</td>
            {% for core in corevalues %}
                <td colspan="8"><input type="hidden" value="{{core.id}}" name="core">{{core.Description}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for corevalues in corevaluesperiod %}
                <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px"><input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coredescription">{{corevalues.Description}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Student's Name</td>
            {% for corevalues in period %}
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for students in student %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" name="student">{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}" name="marking">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.id}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.id}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.id}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.id}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.id}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select>
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="m.id">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

this is what its looks like

[image]

this is my code for inserting data

```
global marking,coreperiod,corevalues
id = request.POST.get('teacher')
teacher = EmployeeUser(id=id)

coreid = request.POST.get('core')
core = CoreValues(id=coreid)


corevalues = []
for corevaluesid in request.POST.getlist('coredescription'):
    corevalues.append(corevaluesid)



coreperiodID = request.POST.get('coreperiod')
coreperiod = gradingPeriod(id = coreperiodID)


marking = []
for markingID in request.POST.getlist('marking'):
    marking.append(markingID)
    print(markingID)


for desc,m in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('marking')):
    coredesc = corevalues[desc]
    print(corevalues[desc])
    coredescription = CoreValuesDescription(id=coredesc)
    print("behavior",m)
    for student in request.POST.getlist('student'):
        students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
        V_insert_data = StudentsCoreValuesDescription(
            Core_Values=coredescription,
            Marking=m,
            Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
            grading_Period = coreperiod,
        )
        V_insert_data.save()
```

i didnt receive any error but
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your select options don't have names, and that is why it didn't get all data:

```
<form method="post" action="/studentbehavior/" id="myform" class="myform" style="width: 100%" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="tblcore">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Core Values</td>
            {% for core in corevalues %}
                <td colspan="8"><input type="hidden" value="{{core.id}}" name="core">{{core.Description}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for corevalues in corevaluesperiod %}
                <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px"><input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coredescription">{{corevalues.Description}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Student's Name</td>
            {% for corevalues in period %}
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coreperiod">Q {{corevalues.id}}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for students in student %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" name="student">{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}" >{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select  name="marking">
                    <option  >--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select  name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select  name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="marking">
                    <option>--------</option>
                    {% for m in marking %}
                        <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

and doing this to my views

```
   for desc, m in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('marking')):
        coredesc = corevalues[desc]
        coredescription = CoreValuesDescription(id=coredesc)

    for student in request.POST.getlist('student'):
        students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
        V_insert_data = StudentsCoreValuesDescription(
            #Teacher=teacher,
            Core_Values=coredescription,
            Marking=m,
            Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
            grading_Period = coreperiod,
        )
        V_insert_data.save()
```